# auto registering JNDI resources

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, glassfish-3

I would like to know is it possible to completely register a JNDI resource for a mysql database connection pool just through deploying a war file. Is this possible?

Or is there any other way to work with JNDI files without the admin console. I have a assignment where i have to use JSTL to access the database and we have to deploy this on a central glassfish 3 server on which we dont have access to the admin console. Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of resources do you want to lookup by JNDI? Starting from `Java EE 6`, EJB components have portable JNDI names, so no configuration required.

Comment: I am trying to create a mysql database connection using JNDI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to configure resources without the interaction with the admin console, but this would be server-specific. For example, for glassfish, you would have to create a `glassfish-resources.xml` file and put it under `WEB-INF`. Here are the sample contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">

<resources>
<jdbc-connection-pool
 name="jdbc/test_pool"
 res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource"
 pool-resize-quantity="1"
 max-pool-size="5"
 steady-pool-size="0"
 statement-timeout-in-seconds="30" >
   <property name="PortNumber" value="1527"></property>
      <property name="Password" value="APP"></property>
      <property name="User" value="APP"></property>
      <property name="serverName" value="localhost"></property>
      <property name="DatabaseName" value="testConnection"></property>
      <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true"></property>
 </jdbc-connection-pool>
 <jdbc-resource pool-name="jdbc/test_pool" jndi-name="jdbc/test"></jdbc-resource>
</resources>
```

Pay attention, that the created resource will be **application-scoped**. This means, that you'll have to use `java:app` prefix to find it by JNDI name, like so:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestConnectionBean implements Serializable {

    @Resource(name = "java:app/jdbc/test")
    private javax.sql.DataSource dataSource;

    public void test() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
        System.out.println(metaData.getDriverName());
        System.out.println(metaData.getDatabaseProductName());
    }

}
```

If you need to create a global-scoped resource, then you'll have to use one of the following:

- admin console
- CLI asadmin utility
- edit domain.xml manually